# Strange effect with ImageView startAnimation in ListView

Tags: android, android-widget, android-animation

after some months of coming here now and then it's finally my turn to submit my problem :

I have a ListView with a custom ArrayAdapter that loads images from the internet (one image per row). I made an ImageCache class that calls an onImageLoaded method on my ArrayAdapter :

```
public void onImageLoaded(Bitmap image, ImageView view){
    view.setImageBitmap(image);
    Utils.log("start animation : " + view.toString());
    view.startAnimation(mAnim);
}
```

The problem is each time startAnimation (supposedly a fadeIn) is called on ONE ImageView, the animation seems to re-run from the start on ALL ImageView-s currently being animated, causing some weird blinking of several (or all) images when scrolling.

Utils.log say that startAnimation is called normally though (ie only once for each new ImageView appearing in the ListView).

The content of my animation XML is as such :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:shareInterpolator="true">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="400"/>
</set>
```

Has this ever happened to anyone? 
Can you see what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is cause by loading the Animation and storing it instead of creating a new Animation each time.

Solution example:

```
public void onImageLoaded(Bitmap image, ImageView view){

    view.setImageBitmap(image);
    Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fade_in);
    view.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
}
```

Note the addiction of this line of code to the method above:

```
Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fade_in);
```

Comment: Yes that's correct, thanks. I found out about it some time ago and should have posted the solution back, my bad. Thanks anyway, this may be useful to other people.